# URL Query string not working! How do I fix this?

Tags: json, string, api, http, url

I set up a web API recently, as a online json API. This is what it looks like.

```
[
    {
        "staffID": "b7fe0bb3-cfda-459e-8f08-178209336c2d",
        "staffName": "Mary Liew",
        "staffEmail": "Maryliew@gmail.com",
        "staffContact": 94234567,
        "staffRole": "Manager"
    },
    {
        "staffID": "95b1be9f-ce33-45a4-8c89-61e2adcfbb83",
        "staffName": "Darren Tan",
        "staffEmail": "Darrentan@gmail.com",
        "staffContact": 84556800,
        "staffRole": "Admin"
    },
    {
        "staffID": "d4e9fcff-d8f0-4b94-9d70-8d8f2b669fc7",
        "staffName": "John Dow",
        "staffEmail": "Johndow@gmail.com",
        "staffContact": 92545622,
        "staffRole": "Part-Timer"
    },
    {
        "staffID": "5be38475-7eb3-4f53-9f59-c5945ba98003",
        "staffName": "Simon Haines",
        "staffEmail": "Simonhaines@gmail.com",
        "staffContact": 92726392,
        "staffRole": "Part-Timer"
    },
    {
        "staffID": "f9431d8c-8315-4432-9e07-f36bc4f5db60",
        "staffName": "Jovan Lim",
        "staffEmail": "Johndow@gmail.com",
        "staffContact": 92563839,
        "staffRole": "Part-Timer"
    }
]
```

The problem comes when I try to query the Url. The link is localhost:500/api/commands. I've tried to filter it to the first staff by using:

```
localhost:500/api/commands?staffContact=94234567
and
localhost:500/api/commands?staffRole=Manager
```

But somehow it still returns the exact same thing. The entire page gets returned. Any help would be appreciated. Have been stuck with this for the past few days.

Comment: When you share the framework, runtime and/or programming language that you are using and use those tags you might get the attention of the specialists

Comment: Does your endpoint take in other parameters to filter the data? APIs do not automatically filter data based on querystrings, you have to write code to handle that on the backend.